# T-SQL Like query performance + doing cross join

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-like

```
                WITH tst
            AS (
                SELECT nz.sPostcode op
                    ,zp.nZoneCountryID
                    ,zp.sPostcode
                    ,zp.nZoneID
                    ,zp.nInjectionID
                FROM dbo.tblZonePostcode zp
                INNER JOIN tblNewZone nz ON nz.nPostcodeID = zp.NewZoneId
                WHERE CHARINDEX('%', zp.sPostcode) = 1
                    AND zp.sPostcode IS NOT NULL
                    AND isnumeric(zp.sPostcodeRange) = 0
                )
            SELECT *
            INTO #tmptst
            FROM tst;

            CREATE INDEX idx_sPostcode12 ON #tmptst (sPostcode);

            CREATE INDEX idx_x1 ON #tmptst (nZoneCountryID);

            CREATE INDEX idx_x2 ON #tmptst (nInjectionID);

            CREATE INDEX idx_x3 ON #tmptst (nZoneID);

            UPDATE #tmprec
            SET calculatedPostCodeZone = (
                    SELECT TOP 1 zp.op
                    FROM #tmptst zp
                    WHERE zp.nZoneCountryID = CalculatedCountryId
                        AND zp.nInjectionID = CalculatedinjectionPointId
                        AND zp.nZoneID = CalculatedZoneId
                        AND CHARINDEX(zp.sPostcode, sConsigneePostcodeFirst) = 1
                    )
            WHERE CalculatedRateChartGroupID > 0
                AND calculatedRatechartValues IS NULL
                AND calculatedPostCodeZone IS NULL
                AND CalculationStatus IS NULL
                AND 0 < (
                    SELECT count(1)
                    FROM #tmptst
                    );
```

In total with tst, in total contains 85k records and #tmprec contains 255k records. Objective of above query is to get matchig postcode from tblNewZone for records postcode starting with matching sConsigneePostcodeFirst.

Issue is above query is taking 7 minutes to execute. I have added Index to the query , tried like query, tried Text search Index.

Please let me know if any thing I can do to improve the query.

Comment: Top 1 is non-deterministic without a unique order by

Comment: I see several operations, which one do you want to improve?